# How to run node.js cli with experimental-specifier-resolution=node?

Tags: node.js, yargs

Our team has built a small CLI used for maintenance. The package.json specifies a path for with the `bin` property, and everything works great; `"bin": { "eddy": "./dist/src/cli/entry.js"}`

Autocompletion is achived by using `yargs@17.0.1`. **However** we recently converted the project to use es6 modules, because of a migration to Sveltekit, i.e. the package.json now contains `type: module`. Because of this, the CLI now only works if we run with:

**what works**

```
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node ./dist/src/cli/entry.js help
```

However, if we run this without the flag, we get an error "module not found":

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module...
```

**So the question is**

Can we somehow "always" add the `experimental-specifier-resolution=node` to the CLI - so we can continue to use the shorthand `eddy`, and utilize auto completion?

Comment: If your CLI is written in TypeScript, I can share the solution. And can you help with a few details? Are you able to run the CLI with `npm start`?

Comment: Hi @VinaySharma  - yes the CLI is written in Typescript, part of a mono-repo. We don't run the CLi with npm start, but with `node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node ./dist/src/cli/entry.js help`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two probable solutions here.

##### Solution 1

Your `entry.js` file should start with a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env node`. You cannot specify the flag directly here, however, if you could provide the absolute path to node directly in the shebang, you can specify the flag.

Assuming you have node installed in `/usr/bin/node`, you can write the shebang in `entry.js` like:

```
#!/usr/bin/node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node
```

(Use `which node` to find the absolute path)

However, this is not a very portable solution. You cannot always assume everyone has node installed in the same path. Also some may use nvm to manage versions and can have multiple version in different path. This is the reason why we use `/usr/bin/env` to find the required node installation in the first place. This leads to the second solution.

##### Solution 2

You can create a shell script that would intern call the cli entry point with the required flags. This shell script can be specified in the `package.json` `bin` section.

The shell script (`entry.sh`) should look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/bin/env node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node ./entry.js "$@"
```

Then, in your `package.json`, replace bin with:

```
"bin": { "eddy": "./dist/src/cli/entry.sh"}
```

So when you run `eddy`, it will run the `entry.js` using `node` with the required flag. The `"$@"` in the command will be replaced by any arguments that you pass to `eddy`.

So `eddy help` will translate to `/usr/bin/env node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node ./entry.js help`

Comment: How do I include the `entry.sh` file, so it's part of the `tsc` build output? (currently it's not included)

Comment: You can use gulp or grunt to automate copying the file to dist. (The same way you handle static assets like images)

Comment: Ok - so I just copied the file over manually, rebuilt everything, but still get module not found..

Comment: Are you sure running this command directly still works: `/usr/bin/env node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node ./entry.js help` . 

If it works, can you try `./entry.sh help`

Comment: wait I actualy never tried the first solution! The first solution seems to work fine ✅

Comment: If you are trying to set up a typescript project, this is a nightmare. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Vivek Are you sure you can not pass flags as part of the hashbang? It seems to work for me. I have used this successfully to execute Node with ESM and TS support [here](https://github.com/0x80/firestore-facade/blob/main/packages/cli/src/cli.ts). 

I have only tested this on MacOS...

Solution 2 I could not get working because ./entry.js is resolved from the CWD and not the file location of the bash script. In my case, that was problematic because like the OP I am executing this as an NPM package bin script. The CWD would then be the project root where the command is being executed.

Comment: @ThijsKoerselman How shebangs treat arguments are specific to operating systems and doesn't seem to be standardised. It might work on MacOS (I haven't tried), but I can confirm this doesn't work on recent Ubuntu releases. This article might be helpful: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-sh-utils/2002-04/msg00020.html

Comment: Hi @Vivek - I ended up using solution 2 as it is more robust. However I'm having issues with auto-completion. Created a question here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/70496353/3694288. I hope you have an idea about what I can do to make it work 

Comment: solution #1, node `v18.7.0` getting error `Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.`

Answer (score -2):

Just add a script to your package.json:
Assuming index.js is your entry point and package.json is in the same directory

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node index.js"
  }
}
```

Then you can just run on your console:

```
npm start
```

Comment: This is not using the package.json bin field