# How to get yargs auto-complete working, when using --experimental-specifier-resolution=node

Tags: node.js, bash, yargs

My objective is to write a CLI in Typescript/node.js, that uses `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node`, written in yargs with support for autocompletion.

To make this work, I use this `entry.sh` file, thanks to this helpful [SO anwswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68154775/3694288) (and the `bin: {eddy: "./entry.sh"}` options in package.json points to this file)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

full_path=$(realpath $0)
dir_path=$(dirname $full_path)
script_path="$dir_path/dist/src/cli/entry.js"

# Path is made thanks to: https://code-maven.com/bash-shell-relative-path
# Combined with knowledge from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68111434/how-to-run-node-js-cli-with-experimental-specifier-resolution-node

/usr/bin/env node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node $script_path "$@"
```

This works great, and I can use the CLI. However, autocompletion does not work. According to yargs I should be able to get autocompletion by outputting the result from `./entry.sh completion` to the `~/.bashrc` profile. However this does not seem to work.

Output from `./entry.sh completion`:

```sh
###-begin-entry.js-completions-###
#
# yargs command completion script
#
# Installation: ./dist/src/cli/entry.js completion >> ~/.bashrc
#    or ./dist/src/cli/entry.js completion >> ~/.bash_profile on OSX.
#
_entry.js_yargs_completions()
{
    local cur_word args type_list

    cur_word="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    args=("${COMP_WORDS[@]}")

    # ask yargs to generate completions.
    type_list=$(./dist/src/cli/entry.js --get-yargs-completions "${args[@]}")

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${type_list}" -- ${cur_word}) )

    # if no match was found, fall back to filename completion
    if [ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
      COMPREPLY=()
    fi

    return 0
}
complete -o default -F _entry.js_yargs_completions entry.js
###-end-entry.js-completions-###
```

I tried modifying the `completion` output, but I don't really understand bash - just yet

**Update**

Working on a reproducible example (WIP).
Repo is [here](https://github.com/21RISK/yargs-autocomplete).

Currently one of the big differences is that `npm link` does not work the same in the 2 different environments. It's only in the repo where I'm trying to reproduce that `/usr/local/share/npm-global/bin/` is actually updated. Currently trying to investigate this.

Comment: Did you restart Bash after modifying its startup file?

Comment: As an aside, you should generally use double quotes around all variables which contain file names. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Hi @tripleee - thanks for giving me that hint. What variable are you thinking about here? The `type_list`?

Comment: `$0` and `$full_path` are both unquoted. That will work as long as they contain trivial file names, but blow up if you have paths with spaces in them etc.

Comment: Can you try providing the full path of entry.js instead of `./dist/src/cli/entry.jsˋ in the completion function ?

Comment: I added quotes and also tried the full path - no luck. I also tried to remove the intermediate bash file, and pointing directly to the js entry file. No luck either..

Comment: The completions work fine for me with the repo files you provided. Is this expected currently?

Comment: Hi @Amir - I think I found out why this was not working in Github codespaces. Will update the question/answer soon

Comment: @DauleDK It looks like `scriptName` fixed your issue though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, everyone. The solution I ended up with, was 2 fold:

1. I added a `scriptName` to the yargs config
2. In the `.sh` file "wrapping", I used `which node` to probably set the `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` flags.

**test-cli.js**

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

import yargs from 'yargs'
import { hideBin } from 'yargs/helpers'
import { someOtherModule } from './some-other-module';

someOtherModule();

yargs(hideBin(process.argv))
  .command('curl <url>', 'fetch the contents of the URL', () => {}, (argv) => {
    console.info(argv)
  })
  .command('curlAgain <url>', 'fetch the contents of the URL', () => {}, (argv) => {
    console.info(argv)
  })
  .demandCommand(1)
  .help()
  .completion()
  .scriptName('eddy') // <== Added thanks to konsolebox
  .parse()
```

**test-cli.sh**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

full_path="$(realpath "$0")"
dir_path="$(dirname $full_path)"
script_path="$dir_path/test-cli.js"

node_path="$(which node)" # <== Makes it work on github codespaces 

$node_path --experimental-specifier-resolution=node $script_path "$@"
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "lets-reproduce",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "yargs": "^17.3.1"
  },
  "bin": {
    "eddy": "./test-cli.sh"
  }
}
```

Steps to install autocompletion:

1. run `npm link`
2. run `eddy completion >> ~/.bashrc`
3. `source ~/.bashrc`
4. profit

Comment: I also suggest placing `$node_path` and `$script_path` around double-quotes just to avoid unexpected word splitting or globbing. The necessity to use `node_path="$(which node)"` is odd. Maybe codespaces has an exported node function which you can also bypass by adding `unset -f node`, or simply by running the command with `exec`.  So it becomes `exec node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node "$script_path" "$@"`. To check if there's a function, use `type node`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try specifying the [scriptName](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/pull/1143/files) in your `entry.js` file to the name of your wrapper script.  This may force generation of completion name using it.  I haven't tried it but looking at the source code of yargs, it looks like the `$0` parameter can be altered using `scriptName`, which in turn will affect how the completion-generation function generate the completion code:

In `yargs-factor.ts`:

```
  scriptName(scriptName: string): YargsInstance {
    this.customScriptName = true;
    this.$0 = scriptName;
    return this;
  }
```

In `completion.ts`:

```
  generateCompletionScript($0: string, cmd: string): string {
    let script = this.zshShell
      ? templates.completionZshTemplate
      : templates.completionShTemplate;
    const name = this.shim.path.basename($0);

    // add ./ to applications not yet installed as bin.
    if ($0.match(/\.js$/)) $0 = `./${$0}`;

    script = script.replace(/{{app_name}}/g, name);
    script = script.replace(/{{completion_command}}/g, cmd);
    return script.replace(/{{app_path}}/g, $0);
  }
```

Also I'm not sure how the `"bin"` configuration works but maybe because of `scriptName` you'd no longer need a wrapper.

Make sure the version of yargs you use supports this.

Also as a side note I thought about suggesting to modify the generated completion script directly but besides being hackish that might also still lead to the script name being unrecognized during completion.  Anyhow I just looked at the right approach first.

The modified version would like this:

```
_entry.sh_yargs_completions()
{
    local cur_word args type_list

    cur_word="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    args=("${COMP_WORDS[@]}")

    # ask yargs to generate completions.
    type_list=$(/path/to/entry.sh --get-yargs-completions "${args[@]}")

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${type_list}" -- ${cur_word}) )

    # if no match was found, fall back to filename completion
    if [ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
      COMPREPLY=()
    fi

    return 0
}
complete -o default -F _entry.sh_yargs_completions entry.sh
```

Another note: If the script name needs to be dynamic based on the name of its caller, you can make it identifiable through an environment variable, so in `entry.sh` you can declare it like this:

```
export ENTRY_JS_SCRIPT_NAME=entry.sh
node ...
```

Then somewhere in `entry.js`, you can access the variable name through this:

```
process.env.ENTRY_JS_SCRIPT_NAME
```

Maybe even just specify `$0` or `${0##*/}` whatever works:

```
export ENTRY_JS_SCRIPT_NAME=$0
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer - trying everything out. So far no luck - but still trying :)

Comment: You need to update your question on what you tried so far. It needs the right combination to be done right.

Comment: At least post the generated completion script you're now using and make sure it's loaded.

Comment: I'm creating a small reproducible environment - hang on :)

Comment: Updated the question, will continue to post findings.

Comment: I loaded your project. it doesn't seem to have completions enabled yet. To see the current active completions, enter `complete -p`.  And then to examine a function, type `type (function_name)`.

Comment: I saw you remove the .sh file and just used the .js file directly. The completion works well if you enable it with `. <(./test-cli.js completion)`.

Comment: Currently I'm struggling with the fact that my reproduction env gets `Linux 11`, but my "real" repo only get's `Linux 10`.... Despite they have the exact same Docker file, and I started-stopped the codespaces...

Comment: Maybe the difference is in the docker versions where supported images vary. Just a guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240571/discussion-between-dauledk-and-konsolebox).

Comment: There is no "Linux 10" or "Linux 11", do you mean Debian 10 / 11?